# The element type 'String' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter, would like to do a List to display the image and title in Grid View Builder however I met an error. I also have to call out the list however not sure what's the issue for the error which I'm don't know how to fix. Error coming out on the code with "**appItem.items[i].appImage**". Much appreciate your help!

```
  List<AppProfile> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }
```

My array(still have quite a lot however only take these two for example)

```dart
 List<AppProfile> _items = [
    AppProfile(
      appID: "",
      title: "Whatsapp",
      appImage: "assets/images/Materials-03.png",
      appLink: "",
    ),
    AppProfile(
      appID: "",
      title: "Wechat",
      appImage: "assets/images/Materials-04.png",
      appLink: "",
    ),
  ]
```

**in my builder/ display file**

```dart
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appItem = Provider.of<AppLogic>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Your Social Media"),
        ),
        body: 
        Container(
          child: GridView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 2 / 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 30, //spacing between column
              mainAxisSpacing: 20,
            ),
            itemCount: appItem.items.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget> [

                    **appItem.items[i].appImage**,
                  ]
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        );
```

**Error occurs**
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this SocialProfileScreen Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that SocialProfileScreen is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

**However in my home page have floating button**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    // "Navigator.push" returns a Future and "onPressed" accepts void
    //so cannot directly use "Navigator" but if using () =>
    //simply means that executing "Navigator..."
    onPressed: () =>
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SocialProfileScreen.routeName),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because your `appItem.items[i].appImage` returns a `String` instead of a Widget. In this case, you need to wrap it with a Widget that displays an image.
However, you can't use a `String`, `double`, `bool` or other variables into a list which is the Widgets list.
So you should add an `Image.assets()` widget or another one (which displays images), and give your image path.

**Like:**

```dart
Image.asset(appItem.items[i].appImage);
```

Comment: First, thank you for your help however once I wrap it with the code you mention it's coming another error. May I know is there any problem from the design of my code?                                                                                                                **Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppLogic> above this SocialProfileScreen Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

Comment: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AppLogic> above this SocialProfileScreen Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

Comment: Maybe restart your app. This error has to do something with
`final appItem = Provider.of<AppLogic>(context, listen: false);`. Did you correctly ```Provider(
  create: (context) => AppLogic(),
  child: ...
)```